# iPhone: get application absolute path

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to programmatically get absolute path of executable. During execution of this executable, i mean :) Something as reading /proc/pid/* in linux for current PID

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure it's a meaningful question for iPhone applications. Why do you need this information - there is probably a better question to ask.

Comment: Agreed. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Any clues, we're interested...

Comment: sorry, you are right :) i just started to explore iPhopne development and the question was derived from the method i used to load game resources in Windows... The answer about NSBundle turn me on the right direction though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this, but:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath];
```

should get you what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You might get close with [NSHomeDirectory](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory).